# Messages sent from journey aren't being received and Email doesn't delivers to outlook

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, dataextensions, mobileconnect

Hope you're having a good time.

Recently, I've been facing an issue with journeys. I created a journey taking a data extension as an entry source to test email and messages send via journey. Emails are being delivered to clients other than outlook whilst messages are getting hard bounced. Sometimes it shows messages are sent successfully but they are never received at the user's end.

The DE as entry source is sendable that is timely filed with salesforce synced data by an automation activity. It has the required fields for message send. Locale, Mobile Number, and ID.

Another problem that I'd like to highlight is that a few screens of Marketing Cloud appear weird. For Instance: Reports and MobileConnect section. It doesn't show the text. Instead, it is showing the variable's name at the backend. Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snfiq.png - This has been tested with different PCs and browsers.

If anybody has had experience with this problem and suggest a solution, that'd be helpful.

Screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql4Qs.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Been a long time since I posted this question.

Here are the answers:

For 1: Contacted SFMC Support and shifted our IP to a new one (private) which resolved our problem. (Ofc did the IP warmup again).

For 2: Contacted SFMC Support. They guided that it could be due to the unsupported language. Switched language to their supported one. English US.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two issues, which both should be addressed through Salesforce support.

1. Your issues with emails to Outlook are not related to SFMC itself, but are caused by your IP/Sender domain being blocked in their end, due to poor sender reputation. This area is referenced to as deliverability, and Microsoft is notorious for blocking even entirely legitimate senders following best practice for sends. There is a number of good articles on this topic, a.o. [this one](https://www.spamresource.com/2021/08/why-does-microsoft-hate-you.html).
   Regardless, you should ask Salesforce to assist you in resolving this issue, by looking into some details on how Microsoft perceives you as a sender. If you want to see these details yourself, [here’s a guide](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314917&type=1) describing how to gain access to the SNDS tool.
2. Here, there is also not much the community can do. It looks like a glitch somewhere in your SFMC environment. Do log a separate ticket on this issue.

Comment: Hey Lukas, I've the ticket logged with SFMC but they seem to be too busy. About email deliverability, my guess is the same as you stated. While I can not understand the reason message getting bounced when sent by journey. When it works perfectly when sent through MobileConnect.